# Windbg memory size in heap summary did not match the usage statistic

Tags: memory-leaks, heap-memory, windbg

I have a `.dmp` file, created from TaskManager. When using windbg command:

```
!heap -s
```

it shows result like this:

[image: !heap -s result]

In this line:

```
00a40000 00000002 1084772 1074756 1084772 339109  3979   218    4     6b   LFH
```

we can see the memory usage is about 1Gb, then I use the command

```
!heap -stat -h 00a40000
```

to check the usage statistic, the result shows here:

[image: !heap -stat -h 00a40000 result]

The question here is: from the statistic, the top line is:

```
a0 24 - 1680  (17.14)
```

which means the memory used is **1680(HEX) = 5Kb**, and the total memory is **5Kb / 17.14% = 29.17Kb**, which is quite different from 1Gb in the summary.

Did I make any mistake here? How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Note that it is a percentage of the **busy** blocks, not of the commited memory, which is quite different.

Comment: That heap also has 4 virtual blocks, which can be really large.